# LPTHW EX25 - not running normally in powershell

Tags: python, powershell

I am following zed shaw's book LPTHW and stuck on ex25. I have typed the code accordingly without errors. If I understand it right he has asked to run it first normal in powershell but when I put the command:
    C:/mystuff> python ex25.py ,

It enters to next line without any output.

I tried importing ex25 in python interpreter this is the error i get:

```
>>import ex25
>>sentence = "All good things come to those who wait."
>>words = ex25.break_words(sentence)
```

After this I get an error:

```
Traceback <most recent call last>:
file stdin in line 1 <module>
file ex25.py line 3 in break_words
words = stuff.split(' ')
Value error: empty separator.
```

what am I doing wrong? Also i experimented for over half hour now trying different solutions , make it work. I guess the powershell wont respond because the program is basically a bunch of functions , without any input. But in the interpreter we do give an input of a sentence , then why the error? Doing my head-in.

the code link for LPTHW: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex25.html

Comment: Just by the way here, but the title of that course is accurate: it really is the hard way to learn Python. It's buggy and unclear. I recommend the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: It worked for me. `In [3]: ex25.break_words(sentence)` gives 
`Out[3]: ['All', 'good', 'things', 'come', 'to', 'those', 'who', 'wait.']`

Comment: Open the python file (ex25.py) and check that there is a space between the quotation marks in the break_words function.

Comment: Thanks @James. sorted. But was that space causing an error? if so, why?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3  I disagree , I like the book and the way its structured. learning loads.

Comment: You are far from the only person who has asked a question here about that course. Sometimes the problem is an actual bug or piece of misinformation. By contrast, I have never seen anyone have a problem with the official tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your code for ex25 but here is mine for the line it says you have error on

```
def break_words(stuff):
   """This function will break up words for us."""
    words = stuff.split(' ')
    return words
```

It works for me you can make a new file and put that portion of your code and mine then compare them if they are exactly the same with 0 difference then tell me. if you can can you post that part of your code in the question

Comment: just realised this was march of last year my mad